# Suppressing `Buffer() is deprecated` warning

Tags: node.js

How can I suppress *only* the `Buffer() is deprecated` warnings in Node.js, without losing other warnings?

```
ERROR   (node:8) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

I know that `Buffer()` is deprecated, and none of my code uses it, but I have dependencies far down the chain that are using it, and I can't immediately fix this, so I'd like to silence the warnings, because they are automatically sent to Slack and it makes it hard to see real errors from my application.

I have tried:

```js
    process.on('warning', (warning) => {
      if (!warning.message.includes('Buffer() is deprecated')) {
        console.error(warning);
      }
    });
```

But this had no effect. I guess that this notice is sent via some other mechanism.

I have looked at what is required to fix all the dependencies that are calling `new Buffer()` but there are many, some that haven't accepted PRs for years, with failing tests in the main branch etc, so it's not an easy undertaking. Besides, it would take time for all the PRs to be accepted, merged, make their way up the chain. In the mean time, I don't want alerts in Slack every 30 seconds for something I can't do anything about.

Comment: That will catch the event but it will still be printed. You can use --no-deprecation globally. https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_no_deprecation.

Comment: This is running in AWS Lambda so I don't think I can pass CLI flags to the `node` process. Besides, it's _only_ the `Buffer` deprecation I want to suppress. I want to log any other warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit of monkey patch code will silence that specific warning:

```
const origWarning = process.emitWarning;
process.emitWarning = function(...args) {
    if (args[2] !== 'DEP0005') {
        // pass any other warnings through normally
        return origWarning.apply(process, args);
    } else {
        // do nothing, eat the warning
    }
}
```

This code obviously has to be run before the code runs that generates the warning you're trying to suppress.

---

FYI, to figure this out, I took the following steps:

1. I looked in the [Buffer code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js#L160) to see where and how the warning was generated.
2. In that code, I can see that it calls `process.emitWarning(bufferWarning, 'DeprecationWarning', 'DEP0005');`
3. So, I worked up a monkey patch for `process.emitWarning()` that looks for the 3rd argument to be `'DEP0005'` which is specific to this particular warning.
4. Then, I tested it both on the Buffer warning and on another warning to make sure that the Buffer warning was blocked and the other warning was not blocked.
5. Then, I checked the implementation of `process.emitWarning()` [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5c3944fa204f161335ace6e65834c57e7a4b27e9/lib/internal/process/warning.js#L68) to see if there were any flags or other settings that might be able to suppress just that specific warning in case there was a supported or better way to do this.  No such option was found.
6. Confirm that `DEP0005` is used only for this particular warning both with a search in the nodejs repository and in the [warnings doc](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8caa6a9d8c153376d86fbed3a58cfae3555ae47b/doc/api/deprecations.md#dep0005-buffer-constructor).